# Time and Space Complexity of given algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory, space-complexity

I am having an algorithm and wanted to find it time and space complexity.
Algorithm is

```
 Algorithm for Scheduling
 INPUT:P1,P2, PN // N processes
 do
  Sort processes in ascending according to their burst time 
  TQ = median of burst time of processes 
  For (i=1 to N )
   Assign TQ to Process Pi 
   If Burst time of process i < TQ 
    remove Process i from array
   Else
    BT of process i = BT of process i - TQ
  Compute waiting time for all process in array
 While (array of processes != empty)
```

How to calculate time and space complexity of this algorithm?

Comment: How do you `remove` and `push`? Do you need the WC or AC ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I updated algorithm and part where pushing process back to array in skipped now. For Removing ,simply set its Burst time (BT) to zero

Comment: What does the last line?  "Compute waiting time..."

Comment: @PF.Castro An array is there that stores Waiting time of each process and in each  iteration waiting time of process it updated. I have not shown detail of that part but it takes O(1) to update Waiting time of a process

Comment: *"simply set its Burst time (BT) to zero"*: that is not the same as removal. This affects the task **Compute waiting time for all process in array**, **Sort** and **median**, which would have to somehow skip zeroes.

Comment: Your algorithm presentation is too inaccurate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In comments you state that it takes *O(1)* to update the waiting time of a process, so that means the following line takes *O(N)*:

```
Compute waiting time for all process in array
```

Concerning the `remove` operation you also suggest that it is *O(1)*, although you should not set the corresponding waiting time to zero, as that would impact other actions on the array (like sorting and getting the median). Better is to copy the last process into slot i, and then drop the last element from the array. That would be *O(1)*.

The execution of the `for` loop then takes *O(N)*. Finding the median in a sorted array is also *O(N)*, so in the `do` body the operation with the greatest time complexity is the sorting: *O(N⋅logN)*

In each iteration of the `do` loop, the array size (*N*) is halved.

So we have the following equation (leaving out the big-O notation):

```
T(N) = N⋅log(N) + T(N/2)
     = N⋅log(N) + (N/2)⋅log(N/2) + (N/4)⋅log(N/4) + ...
     = N⋅(log(N) + (1/2)⋅log(N/2) + (1/4)⋅log(N/4) + ...)
```

Now *log(N/c)* = *log(N) - log(c)*, so we can group terms like follows:

```
     = N⋅((1 + 1/2 + 1/4 + ...)⋅log(N) - log(2)/2 - log(4)/4 - log(8)/8 - ...)
     = N⋅(2⋅log(N) - log(2)/2 - log(4)/4 - log(8)/8 - ...)
     < 2N⋅log(N)
```

So we started out that T(N) is at least *O(N⋅log(N))*, and we derive that it is at most *O(N⋅log(N))*, so we have a tight bound for the time complexity:

*O(N⋅log(N))*